# Solucionado - Problema com uma Web Api chamando outra Web Api

Tags: c#, web-service, asp.net-web-api

Eu sou iniciante desenvolvendo para ambiente web e estou com um problema muito bizarro, por isso o texto deve ficar longo para tentar explica-lo.

Tenho o seguinte cenário:
Um front-end feito em Angular que chama uma Web Api(1), esta Web Api, por sua vez, em alguns casos chama métodos em outra Web Api(2). Todos os métodos funcionam bem com uma exceção.

Um destes métodos da Web Api(1) quando chama o método na Web Api(2) demora muito para receber uma resposta, muitas vezes caindo por timeout. 
Quando uso o Fiddler para chamar diretamente o método na Web Api(2), este responde rapidamente.

Agora a coisa começa a ficar bizarra.
Eu derrubei a Web Api(2) para receber um erro mas, apesar de todos os outros métodos que chamam a Web Api(2) receberem rápidamente um erro 404, este método especifico demora muito para receber este mesmo erro.

E a coisa vai ficando mais estranha.
Eu criei um método só para verificar se a Web Api(2) esta online e chamo ele antes de fazer a chamada real do método na Wab Api(2) e funciona muito bem para todos, menos para aquele meu método problema. Nele este método de checagem tem o mesmo problema de demora para responder.

Este problema ocorre na maquina de todos os outros desenvolvedores acessando esta Web Api em localhost, mas não acontece no ambiente de produção.

Acredito que o problema esteja no IIS local, mas como sou iniciante nesta área não sei o que olhar lá. Alguém tem uma luz para me dar?  Obrigado.

Comment: Não dá para ajudar com essas informações, posta o método que está apresentando o problema

Comment: O problema foi resolvido. O problema estava ocorrendo porque as duas Web Api estavam rodando na mesma Application Pool no IIS. Quando separei as Web Apis em diferentes Application Pools o problema parou de ocorrer.  Muito obrigado.

Comment: Entendi, poderia postar uma resposta com a explicação? Dessa forma, caso alguém esteja com o mesmo problema, vai conseguir achar uma solução